# Table caption problem. Text goes new line every word

Tags: tables, captions

I've a strange problem with caption of table. The text is shrinked to the center (see picture). This is the code of the table in the example (the result is the same for all the table I made).

```
\begin{table}
  \begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ |l|l| p{8cm}| }
\hline
 \textbf{Test}  & \textbf{test} & \textbf{test} \\
\hline
& test & test. \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{This is the description}
\label{tab:xyz}
\end{table}
```

this is my import list

```
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{import}
```

Any idea how to solve it?

[image: caption error]

edit:
this is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[prodmode,acmtoit]{acmsmall} 
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
      \begin{center}
      \begin{tabular}{ |l|l| p{8cm}| }
    \hline
     \textbf{Test}  & \textbf{test} & \textbf{test} \\
    \hline
    & test & test. \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \caption{This is the description}
    \label{tab:xyz}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

the problem seems to be with the style of the document, which can be downloaded [here](http://www.acm.org/publications/latex_style/v2-acmsmall.zip)

Comment: Suggestion: use `\centering` instead of the center environment to center floats.

Comment: Can you please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that let's us reproduce the issue?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem behavior you're reporting with the list of packages you say you load. I can't even get the caption font to be in sans-serif. Please post a complete MWE that generates the problem you're encountering.

Comment: hi all, i've added the example. and i've figured out that i missused the table. in their example they use a different way to specify captions.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question, so that others can benefit from what you learned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the `acmsmall` class requires this syntax for the table environment:

```
\begin{table}
\tbl{<caption text>\label{<label>}{<table material>}
\end{table}
```

The reason for this is to measure the `<table material>` beforehand and adapt the caption width to it. See section 4.2 of the guide.

So you should type

```
\begin{table}
\tbl{This is the description\label{tab:xyz}}{%
  \begin{tabular}{ |l|l| p{8cm}| }
  \hline
  \textbf{Test}  & \textbf{test} & \textbf{test} \\
  \hline
  & test & test. \\
  \hline
  \end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

[image]